# Кнопка back в брузере

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Как в JSP можно добавить проверку на нажатие кнопки back,
что бы если пользователь нажал эту кнопку выходило окно с предупреждением?

```
<%@ include file="../include/inc.jsp"%><script language="javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "С этой страницы ой как не жалательно переходить назад, вы уверены что хотите этого, если вы перейдете вомзожно транзакция была завершена а вы повторно проведете платеж."; };
</script>
```

Сейчас у меня реализовано таким образом, но она работает при переходе на любую страницу.

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно, http://habrahabr.ru/post/141793/

Comment: но я бы хотел сделать так чтобы она работала только при переходе по кнопке назад, а при остальных переходах она работала, но можно сделать так чтобы она уведомляла всегда кроме одной кнопки, как я могу это сделатьа